# Fundamental vector field

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, group-actions

> Definition: Let $M$ be a smooth manifold on which acts a Lie group $G$. Let $X$ be an element in the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ of $G$, we associate to it the vector field $X_M$ called the fundamental vector field defined by $$X_M(m)= \frac{d}{dt}\biggr\vert_{t=0} e^{-tX}.m.$$

Let $G$ be a Lie group and let $H$ be a Lie subgroup of $H$. Let $M$ be a smooth manifold on which $H$ acts on the left.

Let's consider the  action of  $H$ on $G \times M$ : $$h((g,m)):= (gh,h^{-1}m), \quad h \in H , g \in G , m \in M, $$ and define the manifold $Z$ to be  the quotient $G  \times_H M .$

The group $G$ acts on $Z:= G \times _H M$ by $g'.[g,m]:= [g'g,m].$

Let $X \in \mathfrak{g}$, What is $X_Z$ ? i.e if $[g,m] \in G \times_H M$, then how can we continue this calculation:

$$X_Z([g,m])= \frac{d}{dt}\biggr\vert_{t=0} e^{-tX}.[g,m]= \frac{d}{dt}\biggr\vert_{t=0} [e^{-tX}g,m] ?$$

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: The symbol $[g,m]$ actually is the projection $\pi$ to the quotient of $G \times M$ by the  $H$-action. So you can continue the calculation by introducing the differential $d \pi$ . Namely, $= d \pi (X_G , 0)$ .